# What would be the regular expression for finding "RT @"?? And removing it as a potential result?

Tags: php

I am getting these results from my api query on twitter.

I would like to not display the Retweeted ones.

How would i accomplish this in PHP?

```
RT @BarclaysWealth: RT @BarclaysStock: Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/OaYh7
From: InfoFocus: at: Fri, 07 May 2010 21:02:10 +0000

RT @BarclaysStock: Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/OaYh7
From: BARXdirect: at: Fri, 07 May 2010 16:35:56 +0000

Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/OaYh7
From: BarclaysStock: at: Fri, 07 May 2010 16:35:12 +0000
```

Cheers :),

Comment: If you're going through the API, I'd be surprised if Twitter didn't attach come kind of data to each tweet that told you if it was a retweet or not.

Comment: @bschaeffer - Well that's the funny thing. Those tweets are not actual retweets, it's a common misconception. I just hate that people do not use the internal retweet system and just add the RT prefix. This way you cannot count the number of retweets nor see the original tweet creator. I guess they just dream about their tweet counter all day and night (proper retweets do not increment your tweet count). :)

Comment: @treznik - I guess you would half to account for pre "re-tweet" re-tweets, too. New question that just came to mind... did xzibit invent the re-tweet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$text = 'RT @BarclaysWealth: RT @BarclaysStock: Investment ViewPoint...';
if (preg_match('/^RT @/', $text)) {
 // this one starts with  RT @
} else {
 // does not start with RT @, so do something with it
}
```

Comment: This won't account for RT's that have a comment at the front eg "This is cool RT @foo some text".

Comment: Just drop the ^ in the regex if you want to allow it anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to use a regular expression, and assuming your tweets are in an array called `$tweets`:

```
foreach ($tweets as $tweet)
{
  if (strpos($tweet, "RT @") === FALSE)
  {
    print $tweet;
  }
}
```

See [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) for details.  Might be a tad faster than using regexs too.

Comment: Your example is good, just inverted. He wants to print the non-RT ones. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                             
$d = 'RT @BarclaysWealth: RT @BarclaysStock: Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/
From: InfoFocus: at: Fri, 07 May 2010 21:02:10 +0000                                                                                                     

RT @BarclaysStock: Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/OaYh7                     
From: BARXdirect: at: Fri, 07 May 2010 16:35:56 +0000                                                                                                    

Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/OaYh7                                        
From: BarclaysStock: at: Fri, 07 May 2010 16:35:12 +0000                                                                                                 

';                                                                                                                                                       

echo preg_replace('/(^|(?<=\n))RT @.*?\n\n/s', '', $d);
```

gives

```
Investment ViewPoint - We take a look at what a hung parliament could mean for the UK economy http://bit.ly/OaYh7
From: BarclaysStock: at: Fri, 07 May 2010 16:35:12 +0000
```

If you don't want to remove only entries starting with RT @ but also the ones that have RT @ somewhere inside them use just:

`echo preg_replace('/RT @.*?\n\n/s', '', $d);`

If you have your entries already separated don't use regexp. Just iterate over them and check if `strpos($entry, 'RT @') !== FALSE` and if it does, remove this entry.